# Is there a database of alliances between historical figures?

Tags: political-history

I've been really interested in the human, individual aspect of political alliances. Those get really complicated of course!

So I started wondering, is there a database / website / platform out there that can show connections between historical figures? Maybe like a force-graph because that's what my mind is imagining?

eg. [image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to be looking for some massive database of all the important people in history and all the possible connections between them which is totally impractical. I'm not aware of any such effort.

Many historians do use network analysis and visualization in different ways. Check out the [*Visualizing Historical Networks*](https://histecon.fas.harvard.edu/visualizing/index.html) website at Harvard for lots of examples with an economic focus.

Niall Ferguson is one prominent historian who has written about the historical impacts of network structures, particularly in his book [*The Square and The Tower*](https://www.niallferguson.com/the-square-and-the-tower). Some of the main ideas from that book are also presented in the PBS series [*NetWorld*](https://www.pbs.org/wnet/networld/).

---

EDIT: It occurred to me that Wikidata is probably the closest thing to a general historical database of individuals. [There is a list](https://wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Tools/Visualize_data) of visualization projects people have done with that data, some of which are network oriented. While I don't see anything quite like you are asking for, there are some examples there that might inspire you to build something new.

Comment: Well answered, thank you.